# Cardinality and the set of all convex polygons in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: geometry, elementary-set-theory

I am asked to prove that the set $\mathcal{T}$ of all convex polygons in $\mathbb{R}^2$ has cardinality equal to $2^{\omega}$.

$\textbf{My Attempt:}$ I have previously shown that the set of all open subsets in $\mathbb{R}$ has cardinality equal to $2^{\omega}$.

Here is a quick outline, let $A$ be a member of the set of all open subsets in $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{T}$.

$\forall q \in A$, where $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, there exists a rational radius $r_q$ such that $(q-r_q,q+r_q) \subseteq A$. Then $A=\bigcup_{q \in A} (q-r_q,q+r_1)$.

Every $A \in \mathcal{T}$ is completely defined by the set $\{(r,r_q) : q \in \mathbb{Q} \cap A \}$.

I want to approach the problem where $\mathcal{T}$ is the set of all convex polygons in $\mathbb{R}^2$ in a similar fashion.

However, in the above problem concerning open set I could find a way to completely characterize an open set using members of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Does a convex polygon in $\mathbb{R}^2$ have any such defining characteristics?

Comment: I assume you are including the boundary, right? So all convex polygons are closed. So their complements are open. This gives us an upper bound. Finding a lower bound can be easily done explicitly.

Comment: @Andres I am not sure how to use this fact to prove the above statement.

Answer (score 1):

The space $\mathbb R^2$ has *countable basis*: there is a countable family of sets of which every open set is composed by union. Namely, the set of all disks with rational coordinates of the center and rational radius form such a family.

Therefore, there is an injection from the set of open subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ to $2^\omega$: every set $U$ is matched to the set of basis elements that it contains.

By considering the complement, this gives an injection from the set of closed sets to $2\omega$.

In the opposite direction, there is an injection from $2^\omega$ to the set of convex polygons: consider squares of sidelength $x$.